# Calling a C++ function from a C program

Tags: makefile, scons, undefined-reference

How can I call a C++ function from a C program, is it possible?, and if it is how can I do it?. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are trying to call a C++ function from C, then you are probably running into [name mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) issues. The compiler does this in order to support function overloading and other features of C++.

You can use `extern "C"` to inform the C++ compiler that the function `CMACInit()` will be called from C code:

```
extern "C" CMACInit() { ... }
```

When declared in this way, the C++ compiler will not mangle the name and will set everything up so the function can be called from C code.