# Calling ffmpeg from a C++ program

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ffmpeg

I have seen a similar question here [How to wrap H264 into a mp4 container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21263064/how-to-wrap-h264-into-a-mp4-container) and [Calling a C++ function from a C program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499293/calling-a-c-function-from-a-c-program) but i still need some examples to understand.

1. How can ffmpeg command line be launched from  a c++ program to for instance convert a video?
2. Is it possible to use it in a loop for instance where there are a couple of videos in a directory which need to be converted?

I intend converting raw videos in a folder to mp4 but i want to do so using the command line.Relevant link or sample code will be most helpful.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Some answers here: [What is the equivalent to Posix popen() in the Win32 API?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/450865/45249)

Answer (score 1):

1. The same way you would launch any other external program using C++ program.
2. Yes. Enumerate the videos you need, parse accordingly.